# Android ExoPlayer AVI

Tags: android, видео, exoplayer

В своем приложении использую `ExoPLayer`. Как выясняется, он не может проигрывать avi-файлы.
Вопрос состоит в том, как его научить это делать?

Comment: [см. Customization](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) Extractor – If you need to support a container format not currently supported by the ExoPlayer library, consider implementing a custom Extractor class, which can then be used to together with ExtractorSampleSource to play media of that type. Ну то есть выяснить что в avi написать для него экстрактор.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, мне кажется, ваш комментарий (будучи переведённым на русский) вполне «тянет» на ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на ответ тянет "как". А чтобы ответить "как", надо сначала реализовать у себя, а без информации что за avi скрывается довольно сложно. Ну кроме того, что про ExoPlayer я узнал из этого вопроса, дел с ним не имел. Если metalurgus реализует экстрактор и опубликует ответ будет гораздо интереснее.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, порывшись еще пол дня в интернете я понял, что экстрактор - это пол беды. В AVI контейнере часто используются неподдерживаемые кодеки, вроде DivX. Даже если извлечь, воспроизвести его *руками* будет очень сложно.

Comment: @metalurgus есть вариант посмотреть в сторону vlc, правда последний раз когда на него смотрел он был в альфе...